# Create webservice in drupal

Tags: android, web-services, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Can we create webservices in Drupal? Our web development team is creating a website in Drupal and they want to build an android application for the same and for that I need to use webservices to access the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [services module](http://drupal.org/project/services)

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with
>   Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like
>   REST, XMLRPC, JSON, JSON-RPC, SOAP, AMF, etc. This allows a Drupal
>   site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the
>   same callback code.

It's build for this reason. `Drupalize.me android app` is built on the [services module](http://drupal.org/project/services), so too for many android applications.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 3):

Can we create webservices in Drupal?

> Yes, You can Do it.

I had done it via JSON webservices.